# Image cannot be null using FadeInImage and url [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, image, dart, url

Hello so I added a way to display my url images in a list but because Im fetching this information from public API some of them are missing URLs and errors occur, I tried using placeholder and image errorbuilder but that didnt help

Here is my code:

```
child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                          height: 100,
                          width: 100,
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          image: newsList[index].urlToImage,
                          placeholder: 'images/placeholder.png',
                          imageErrorBuilder: (context, error, StackTrace) {
                            return const Image(
                                height: 100,
                                width: 100,
                                image: AssetImage("images/placeholder.png"));
                          },
                        ),
```

and Error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building:
'package:flutter/src/widgets/fade_in_image.dart': Failed assertion: line 234 pos 15: 'image !=
null': is not true.
```

[image]

Updated Code:

```
child: newsList[index].urlToImage == null
                            ? Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: AssetImage("images/placeholder.png"),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            : FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                                height: 100,
                                width: 100,
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                image: newsList[index].urlToImage,
                                placeholder: 'images/placeholder.png',
                                imageErrorBuilder:
                                    (context, error, StackTrace) {
                                  return const Image(
                                      height: 100,
                                      width: 100,
                                      image:
                                          AssetImage("images/placeholder.png"));
                                },
                              ),
```

and error message:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[imageErrorBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FadeInImage/imageErrorBuilder.html) will only be called if there is an error occurs during image loading, example the image path does not exist.

To fix your issue, you have to check whether url is null or empty. If it is null, display another widget, else display `FadeInImage`.

```
newsList[index].urlToImage == null ? DisplayNoImage: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(...),
```

Comment: First of all thank you for quick reply I followed your instructions and this  is what my code is now along with the error (updated question)

Comment: question not updated.

Comment: Check again I updated it few second ago

Comment: "_A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget_" The latest error shows the `String` in the `Text` widget is **null**. Did the error point to which line?

Comment: When I check the text.dart the line 378 its this :  assert(
         data != null,
         'A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.',
       ),

Comment: Post the full exception.

Comment: I edited question with full exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241619/discussion-between-john-joe-and-don).